# What's goin' on with img's overflow?

Tags: html, css, hover, overflow

When I hover the icon img's overflow changes. All the code you can find here:
https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/12122/

just hover the icon

> P.S. I couldn't use z-index:-1, because part of my img goes under
>   header's background... here is screen: 
>   https://monosnap.com/file/vfivmX7MGJl8bobULiipeToilyTZIx

styles for header:

```
.header {
  background: url("../img/background.png") 100% 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  max-width: 1920px;
  max-height: 900px;
  color: white;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove `position: relative;` from the `CSS` of `img`

```
.avatar img {
    vertical-align: bottom;
    position: relative; //remove this style
  }
```

Comment: Great! But how does it work ? Can you explain how relative position affects this ?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the **position: relative;**.
.avatar img
    {
    vertical-align: bottom;
    }

If you set position: relative; on an element but no other positioning attributes (top, left, bottom or right), it will no effect on it's positioning at all, it will be exactly as it would be.

There are two things that happen when you set position: relative;. One is that it introduces the ability to use z-index on that element, which doesn't really work with statically positioned elements. Even if you don't set a z-index value, this element will now appear on top of any other statically positioned element. You can't fight it by setting a higher z-index value on a statically positioned element. The 2nd thing that happens is it limits the scope of absolutely positioned child elements. Any element that is a child of the relatively positioned element can be absolutely positioned within that block.